# Sending SOAP request via PHP?

Tags: php, soap

I need to send the following SOAP request using PHP:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:sup="url">
  <soapenv:Header/>
  <soapenv:Body>
    <ControlledEnquiryRequest xmlns="url">
        <Authentication>
           <SubscriberDetails>
              <Username>*****</Username>
              <Password>***</Password>
           </SubscriberDetails>
        </Authentication>
        <ControlledRequest>
           <Asset>
              <Name>Tranquility</Name>
           </Asset>
           <ParameterList/>
           <PrimaryProduct>
              <Code>Platinum</Code>
           </PrimaryProduct>
        </ControlledRequest>
     </ControlledEnquiryRequest>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

At the moment I've got:

```
$requestParams = array(
    'CustomerCode' => '*****',
    'Password' => '***'
);

$client = new SoapClient('url?wsdl');
$response = $client->ControlledEnquiryRequest($requestParams);

print_r($response);
```

However I'm getting a 500 error. I'm also unsure on how I pass the other Name and product codes through?

Obviously I'm using the actual URL instead of a 'url'. In Soap UI it's getting a result, but I can't get my head around adapting it to PHP.

Comment: The server probably tells you what's wrong. Enable the trace option and inspect the return value of [__getLastResponse](http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.getlastresponse.php).

Comment: @Peter just realised I'd put 404 error and it's actually a 500 error. Only stops getting the error when I remove `$response = $client->ControlledEnquiryRequest($requestParams);` even adding __getLastResponse() gives a 500 error.

Comment: __getLastResponse() should return some kind of error message. What is it?

Comment: Try doing `$client->__getFunctions()` and make sure that function exists.

Comment: @Peter I don't get any error even using that, just a 500 error and the page doesn't load.

Comment: Try something much simpler for testing the Soap service before losing your mind with how to set it up correctly in PHP. Use something like this : http://www.soapclient.com/soaptest.html to see what the expected arguments are for `ControlledEnquiryRequest`. What you are passing to it now looks very likely wrong. Your life will be much easier when you know whether the problem is with the service, your service calls, or PHP.

Comment: @BA_Webimax That outputs `array(6) { [0]=> string(51) "EnquiryResponse enquire(EnquiryRequest $parameters)" [1]=> string(90) "ParameterizedEnquiryResponse parameterizedEnquiry(ParameterizedEnquiryRequest $parameters)" }`

Comment: If that's what you are getting back for `__getFunctions`, this looks like it's a document-literal style service/WSDL, which php's `SOAPClient` doesn't do too great with on its own (it can do it, but you essentially need to write all of the method calls and soaptypes from scratch). There are third-party SOAP libraries for PHP that play better with non-typed SOAP services like what you are probably looking at. The standard 5-10 years ago would have been nusoap, but I don't know if it's still the go-to.

Comment: This one looks shiny and new. Not sure if it is at all any good. https://github.com/phpro/soap-client

Comment: To make it more clear, try also `$client->__getTypes()`. This will reveal what `parameterizedEnquiry` is expecting in terms of the object structure. Also, notice that your result for `$client->__getFunctions()`, that `ControlledEnquiryRequest` is not a listed function, even though it is the function you are trying to call in your example code.

Comment: @Anthony one thing that stands out from the results of __getTypes to me is that the username/password is in the second array: `[1]=> string(113) "struct AuthenticationType { ServiceVersionType ServiceVersion; CustomerType SubscriberDetails; any; }" [2]=> string(118) "struct CustomerType { CustomerCodeType CustomerCode; InitialsType Initials; PasswordType Password; any; }"`